# error while compiling gcc

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, g++, makefile

I'm trying to compile gcc-code-assist which has the code completion feature in order to use it with emacs. However i have been getting this error message while compilinng

```
checking for exception model to use... configure: error: unable to detect exception model
make[1]: *** [configure-target-libstdc++-v3] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/dev/workspace/trash/gcc-code-assist-0.1-4.4.4'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 64bit 
what can i do to overcome this problem

Comment: What's the configure option you are using?

Comment: Doing some Google searches on this error it sounds like you have an incorrect spelling somewhere in your makefile or an incorrect path specified. Could you post the code inside the makefile? This link also might help you. http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2001-11/msg01262.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the right way to compile it ...
I really didn't have much knowledge of how to compile gcc (my first time)
after reading through the FAQ of building gcc I found the problem.
it turned out that I had to run the **configure** script and **make** from outside the source directory
( I called it gcc-build) so the directory list looked like this

```
gcc-source/
gcc-build/
```

then everything compiled smoothly 
here's the link to the FAQ http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#configure